# Google Places REST call returning 404 not found

Tags: javascript, rest, google-places-api

I would like to search google places based using a REST call. I am trying the following URL format as per Googles documentation, but I"m getting a 404 not found. Can anyone suggest the proper format for a Google Places rest call.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/output?query=newyork&key={MYKEY}&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace `output` with either `json` or `xml`. Change the URL to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=newyork&key={MYKEY}&sensor=false
```

Reference: [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)